# Weird shading when using Cycles rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, light, shadows

I switched to Cycles rendering, because Eevee didn't render the full image. Now, despite the fact that I put a light in the scene, the whole object is lit, even the back. I already tried changing the power of the light and its size, but unfortunately, it did not help. When moving the colour points in the colour ramp, (the shadow colour position and the lit colour position) the object suddenly turns completely lit or completely unlit. The object is or lit or dark, but there's no in between where there are shadows. What is it that is going on and how can it be fixed?
[image]

Comment: This is happening because since the color is connected directly to the Material Output, blender considers this material **unshaded**. .Connect it back through **some** shader node first (Ex: Diffuse BSDF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points here:

- *"Shader to RGB"* does not work for Cycles, it is normally Eevee only.
- The color is directly pluged into the surface output, so this is considered direct color, unshaded.

You should plug a shader to the surface output, starting from this for instance:

[image]